# how to set a size of process regardless of the position of another running process of the same type C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to resize a certain process window with the following code:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "iexplore.exe"};
var p = Process.Start(psi);
while (p.Handle == IntPtr.Zero) 
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
SetWindowPos(p.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 500, 500, 1);
Console.WriteLine(p.Handle);`
```

In this case IExplorer opens in the wanted size, but if there is another IExplorer process open, it locates it according to the other one, with a certain shift (down and to the right) regardless of the size specified in SetWindowPos().

Does anyone know how can I prevent from windows to open the process shifted from the previous one that's open, instead of taking the size given in the function?